# Update table cells based on criteria using an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, macros

I have a dynamic master table on `Worksheets("Jobs")` that has fixed number of columns (A:M). Columns I and J are formulas.
[image]

On a different worksheet I have a textbox that will have a job # specified. I need values in columns L & M to change to "No" for the matching job #. My previous code was working too slow. I'm trying to rewrite the code using an array, but I have a hard time doing so.

The idea is to transfer the entire table to a memory-based array and make your changes to the array, then transfer the updated table data back to the worksheet.

Question is if I do that, wouldn't that clear the content that have formulas. Can I use two arrays from two header based named ranges for column B, then another for columns L:M? Working in that array, just update and transfer the values that just need to be changed.
Thank you for any help anyone can provide.

Here is my code so far:

```
Sub CloseJobarr()

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Txt As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Arr1 As Variant, Arr2 As Variant

    Arr1 = Range("JobCol_Master").Value '<--Column B of Master Data Table that is on ws
    Arr2 = Range("OpenSCCols").Value    '<--Columns L:M of Master Data Table that is on ws
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Jobs")


    With ThisWorkbook
        Txt = .Worksheets("ID").TextBoxID.Text
        If Txt <> "" Then
            With ws
                For Each cell In Arr1
                      'If job# matches textbox and if job# is to correct region then...
                    If cell.Text = Txt And .Cells(cell.row, 4).Value = "ID" Then


                    End If
                Next cell
            End With
        End If
    End With


    MsgBox "Job not found."


End Sub
```

Updated Code below using `Auto Filter` (I'm still experiencing screen flicking). When a job # doesn't match I get a run time error message " no cells were found" and the debug line is: `.Range("OpenSCCols").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "No"`

```
Option Explicit

Sub CloseJobarraytesting()
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Jobs").Unprotect Password:="Andersen"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error GoTo errHndl
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Txt As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet


    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Jobs") '<--| reference relevant worksheet
        .Range("JobCol_Master").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Worksheets("ID").TextBoxID.Text '<--| filter its "JobCol_Master" named range  on textbox ID
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell filtered other than header
            .Range("OpenSCCols").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "No" '<-- write "OpenSCCols" named range filter cells, corresponding to the filtered ID
        Else
            MsgBox "Job not found."
        End If
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

CleanUp:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Jobs").Protect Password:="Andersen"

Exit Sub
errHndl:
    MsgBox "Error happened while working on: " + vbCrLf + _
        vbCrLf + vbCrLf + "Error " + _
        Str(Err.Number) + ": " + Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
        GoTo CleanUp
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you expecting only one match or could there be multiple matches for any given Job# ?

Comment: `For Each cell In Arr1`  Arr1 only has cell values in it.  It has no actual cells.  You get a small performance boost by iterating over an array of range values instead of the range itself. Reading into memory is fast.  Where you get the big performance boost is from writing to a range in a single operation.  If you are only updating a few hundred cells, using`Application.ScreenUpdating = False` will probably be  plenty fast enough.

Comment: Your should watch this series [Excel VBA Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).  This is the relevant video [Excel VBA Introduction Part 25 - Arrays](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9FTX7TgkpM&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&index=28)

Comment: @Thomas Inzina I tried `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` but it had minor improvements. @Tim Williams The Job# column are unique values with no duplicates. I need to find the job# in the Master Table specified in the text box, and if the Jobs region value matches the one stated above in the code `"ID"` then change values in columns L:M for that Job.

Comment: Why is the Else statement not working right? If the autofilter returned zero I get an run time error: no cells found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited** to have the code check filtered cells on `Range("JobCol_Master")`

your aim is to actual filter data, then I believe that an [`AutoFilter()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) approach should be considerable fast

assuming you defined both `JobCol_Master` and `OpenSCCols` named ranges enclosing their corresponding headers cells, you can simply go like follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub CloseJobarr()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Jobs") '<--| reference relevant worksheet
        With .Range("JobCol_Master")
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Worksheets("ID").TextBoxID.Text '<--| filter its "JobCol_Master" named range  on textbox ID
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell filtered other than header
                .Parent.Range("OpenSCCols").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "No" '<-- write "OpenSCCols" named range filter cells, corresponding to the filtered ID
            Else
                MsgBox "Job not found."
            End If
        End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

should your named ranges not contain their headers the code can be easily adapted by means of some `Offset()` and `Resize()` method applied on them, but its much easier (and logic) to resize the named ranges and have them enclose their headers

Comment: This code works but it not fast enough. Screen still flickers. I can see it switch worksheets. Looking to try a solution using an array to see if it's faster.

Comment: You are not using my code while experiencing screen flickering, since it has no worksheets switching.

Comment: I edited my post and included the `Autofilter()` code you provided. see above. Thanks.

Comment: see edited code for the "Else" thing. As for the flickering, not an issue of your _original_ post, my code alone cannot arise it since it has no worksheets switching, so that it must be due to your code general "environment", not shown in your _original_ question. You may try to add `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Jobs").Select` before calling `CloseJobarr`. Should it not work, search in SO. Should you still be stuck, make a _new_ post with all relevant details about your entire code "environment". Finally, if this answer solved your _original_ question, you may want to accept it. Thank you